# Can I remove opencv directory after installation?

Tags: opencv

I have installed opencv successfully. I guess the library has been put to /usr/loca/lib after installation. The problem is I do not have much space on my disk. So can I remove opencv directory completely to save space? I think it is useless after installation, but I am not sure. Does anyone know? Thanks in advance,

Update: I have removed opencv directory completely, and nothing goes wrong. It seems that `make install` has installed the opencv libraries and there is no need to keep source code any more.

Comment: ... until you want to update to a newer version.

Comment: so you mean I can use 'rm' to remove the opencv directory completely and this will not affect the use of opencv library?

Comment: It should be ok, as long as you have done `make install`. I would consider renaming that directory as `OpenCVForRemoval` so nothing can be found in there and seeing if everything works for a few days and then delete it - or zip it all up and compress it onto a USB flash memory stick or somesuch.

Comment: I have done make install. Thanks for your suggestions. I will do as what you said, and see if everything works fine.

Comment: Excellent - thanks for sharing back your findings.